# Guidance vs. Navigation vs. Estimation

Tags: launch, terminology, navigation, guidance

I'm still confused over what exactly falls under the scope of Navigation, Guidance, and Estimation systems.

Say I have a bunch of IMUs and use them to determine my position and orientation and my velocity and acceleration relative to earth. That's navigation, right?

Now say I specify a launch pitch program relative to some earth centered frame and apply some transforms to that program to resolve it on my rocket's main frame in order to compute the pitch errors to correct for with my gimballed engines. Is all of this guidance? Is some or all of this navigation?

And if I calculate my delta-V and time-to-go using thrust, mass flow rate, and instantaneous mass. Am I now doing estimation? What else would fall under the scope of estimation?

Sorry for the rookie question. Thanks if you know and can clarify!

Comment: Where do you see the term "Estimation System" used?

Comment: General nomenclature: A ship's captain charts a course on a map and then gives the helmsman instructions. This is navigation. The helmsman then turns the wheel and adjusts the throttle accordingly to ensure the ship stays on the planned course. This is guidance.

Comment: @Dragongeek that's not the way NASA uses it. See my answer.  They'd say your first thing is guidance and your second thing is flight control.

Comment: Good analogy Dragongreek. @OrganicMarble seems to be right on the terms from what I've read, though. Now, say the helmsman instructions are a set of roll, pitch, yaw errors from some desired orientation. Am I right in saying that the computation of those errors is guidance? Or might they somehow be control? I'm leaning toward the former, but I worry I might be wrong...

Comment: I guess I'm wondering if guidance is *just* the calculation of an appropriate trajectory given a target end point, or if it's also the calculation of the *errors* in the rocket's orientation relative to that trajectory for consumption by the flight control system (where they must be converted into appropriate engine gimbal actuator commands, cold-gas thruster commands, etc). Does guidance include the calculation of the trajectory *and* of the errors, of is just the calculation of the trajectory?

Comment: For shuttle guidance calculated the *attitude the vehicle needed to be in at any given instant to fly the proper trajectory* and flight control *computed and flew out errors between the guidance commanded attitude and the vehicle actual attitude*. Recall that all flight control can do is point the vehicle!

Comment: Thanks @OrganicMarble! So to be sure: Say Guidance calculates a target pitch angle of 30 deg relative to your reference frame. Your rocket is at 15 deg relative to that same reference frame. The calculation of the difference between the two would be done in the flight control system?

Comment: At least for shuttle, yeah, it explicitly says "the control system computes and flies out errors".  (It's a bit more nuanced with filters, etc but yes) You might get a lot out of reading the document linked in my answer.

Comment: This is really just perfect, @OrganicMarble. Thank you thank you.

Comment: A possible correction, though: P. 2-1 of the shuttle manual says "guidance determines if the vehicle is "on course" and computes correction commands if it is not." It seems the correction commands would be the rotations required to bring the shuttle back to its precomputed trajectory---i.e., the rotation errors which would be fed to the flight control system. It seems?

Comment: Also on p. 2-1, it says "Flight control is responsible for converting these course correction commands into vehicle effector [...] movements so as to put the vehicle back "on course." So this too seems to suggest that the flight control system would take in the errors from guidance instead of computing them. Maybe I'm wrong? Either way, thank you thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Now I have some reliable material to fall on :)

Comment: You click on the gray checkmark beside the answer (near the voting arrows). I'm glad I mentioned it!

Comment: See quote on page 3-18 and read the part about G/C STEER. Study the diagram on 3-19.

Comment: Ah! I should think more about the icons I see.

Comment: I can't believe the shuttle navigation system cycled at 0.25-0.5 Hz. That is the slowest rate I've seen mentioned for a rocket/spacecraft so far. Wow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Simply stated, navigation equipment and software keep track of where the [vehicle] is
> located, guidance computes where it needs to be to satisfy mission requirements, and
> flight control gets it there.

[image]

Sources:

- [ASC GNC 2102 Ascent Guidance, Navigation, and Control Workbook](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC%20GNC%20ASC%202102%20Ascent%20Guidance%20and%20Navigation%20and%20Flight%20Control%20Workbook.pdf) (1979)
- G&C I/O/D 21002 Guidance and Control
  Insertion/Orbit/Deorbit Workbook (2004)

Comment: ... and estimation is part of navigation? and possibly guidance?

Comment: @JCRM Not familiar with estimation in the sense used by the OP. I don't think they are talking about Kalman filtering etc.

Comment: Do you have a more modern source? The ASC GNC 2102 is over half a century old...

Comment: @Dragongeek the quote is from the 2nd document (sadly not online) dated 2004.  I don't think anything has changed in the definition.

Comment: @Organic Marble any chance to get a pdf of the second document? I tried to search it in ntrs.nasa.gov but I can't find it

Comment: @ocirocir I don't know of any online